# Insert variable into text search string

Tags: python, python-2.7

These two lines are from a program that carries out a phrase search of Wikipedia and returns the total number of times that the specific phrase occurs. It is essential that the search contains an apostrophe:

```
results = w.search("\"of the cat's\"", type=ALL, start=1, count=1)
print results.total
```

I want to replace the word "cat" with a variable, e.g.

```
q = "cat"
```

so that I can generate the same search format for a list of different words. How do I format the search string to include the variable, please?

Comment: This stringformatting questions have been asked many times. E.g. here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082452/python-string-formatting-vs-format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, Python has some useful string methods that I feel would be very helpful to you. In this case we are going to be using the [`format`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) function. Also, don't me intimidated by `'` or `"`s. You can simply escape them with a backslash. Demo:

```
>>> a = '\''
>>> a
"'"
```

See how the single quote is sandwiched between those double quotes?

You can do the same with double-quotes:

```
>>> a = "\""
>>> a
'"'
>>>
```

Now, to answer your question, you can use the `.format` function that comes with the string class (no imports necessary).

Lets have a look:

```
>>> a = "{}\'s hat"
>>> a.format("Cat")
"Cat's hat"
>>> a.format("Dog")
"Dog's hat"
>>> a.format("Rat") # Rats wear hats?
"Rat's hat"
>>>
```

In your case, you can simply do this:

```
w.search("\"of the {}'s\"".format(<your animal here>), type=ALL, start=1, count=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

With Python you could simply do:

```
q = "cat"
results = w.search("\"of the " + q + "'s\"", type=ALL, start=1, count=1)
print results.total
```

There is also

```
q = "cat"
results = w.search("\"of the %s's\"" & q, type=ALL, start=1, count=1)
print results.total
```

And

```
q = "cat"
results = w.search("\"of the {query}'s\"".format(query=q), type=ALL, start=1, count=1)
print results.total
```

See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082452/python-string-formatting-vs-format) for a more detailed discussion, including performance.